# How to track user face using face recognition in flutter

Tags: flutter, face-recognition

I am currently try to use face recognition in flutter, but I want to know is there a way to track user face... I mean I want to ensure that the user who do face recognition is true person according their photo image inside my database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you must be knowing, Flutter is a mobile app development framework. Something like face recognition is far away from this. You need to keep these separate.

In the Flutter app, you focus on the app design, UI etc. And build a separate face recognition module. There are some face recognition libraries available to use freely. Make use of that. And then integrate the two by means of say REST APIs. One such face recognition library is [opencv](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/24/opencv-face-recognition/).

Comment: from the link that you have given.. is that possible to recognize cartoon face? because I try some packages for face recognition but I still able to detect cartoon image face... I want to know if there is package that can I use for only real face of person

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/Saurav0074/Cartoon-Face-Detection-and-Recognition) library. I didn not run and tested it but seems to be useful.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding here, I try to find package that can recognize real face of person, without face of cartoon

Comment: Oops ! Okay. I haven't tried any of the existing face detection lib for cartoon faces but what I tried just now is - Google Vision API. It tells whether the particular photo is of the cartoon. You can probably make two calls - one to your face detection program and other to GVI. And apply the appropriate filter.  Seems to be a long way.