# How to do face id authentication for both android and iOS in flutter

Tags: android, ios, authentication, flutter, face-id

Hi I try to look for resource about authentication using face id in flutter that available for both android and iOS. I have try to search some resources, but most of them say that face id only available in iOS. are there any guides or resources that I can read to use face id auth for both android and iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FaceID, pattern unlock etc are done on the device. It can't be customised to suit our need e.g. I wanted to use face recognition on iOS to use in my Flutter app but it's not possible.

Secondly, to have face id on Android the device needs to provide this feature. E.g. Pixel 4 can do it but it is not possible in most of the Android phones.

In case this question is connected to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61241944/how-to-track-user-face-using-face-recognition-in-flutter):
Even on iOS, the FaceID, TouchID tells you whether the user is authorised or not. However, we can't get the face/touch parameters so as to store it in our database.

Comment: yea..this question is linked to my question before, I come with this question after I learn that face detector doesn't same with face recognition. what I just want to try after read your idea is to add eye blinking detector using access to camera phone in my flutter app.. do you have any guides or resources to detect eye blinking... I have tried to search about it, but I only get little resource

Comment: I understand. I'd the same journey just a few months back when I was designing the Flutter app with face recognition. Any way, check out [this] (https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/04/24/eye-blink-detection-opencv-python-dlib/ ) for eye blink and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72_7ByIfvEI)

Comment: I am kinda new in flutter.. and flutter uses dart language..from the link that you have given, is that possible to apply python inside flutter?

Comment: These things - face detection, recognition, eye links etc are way better, fater and readymade in Python. Flutter is made to make the client mobile app whereas the face detection etc needs a heavy mathematical processing for which a back-end is more suitable. Of course, both Android and iOS now provides on device ML libs. However, many of the things are readily available with Python libs.

Comment: so what you mean is... first.. I need to know how to use openCV inside flutter ?

Comment: OpenCV is one of such library which is quite easy to use and code is available on the internet. You need to create a REST API and call it from the Flutter app. In theory, you get the image from the Flutter app, upload it to your server, trigger the face rec API and consume the result and display it on the app. Depending on the data size, everything may or may not be synchronous.

Comment: I understand now, just to ensure my doubt... so the backend should work with python right?

Comment: Python is a preferred way, yes. Let's continue the discussion in the chat if you have questions. Please mark the answer as accepted if you think this information helps. Thanks.

Comment: for now I think your explanation is enough, I will add comment to chat you if there is related question.. thank you very much for your help and explanation :D