# How to add Face authentication in flutter for android devices?

Tags: flutter

I want to add the face authentication for andorid but could not find one. No packages are there and not event the solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you look at this package; https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth/example. The package has two type of auth, one is BiometricType.face and another BiometricType.fingerprint.

Comment: @TimurTurbil that doesnot support face unlock in android

Comment: Nobody has implemented yet...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try it:

[How to do face id authentication for both android and iOS in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61262831/how-to-do-face-id-authentication-for-both-android-and-ios-in-flutter)

Youtube:- https://youtu.be/M6Puy4EBrz4

Comment: Its not for andorid i guess.

Comment: My dear guess is not solution. Try and practice is real solution.